# Impress.js: How to modify dom using impress.js

Tags: javascript, impress.js

I am  using impress.js for slides. When I reach the slide number 16, I want impress.js to call a function named `myFunction()` which modifies the DOM. How can I call `myFunction()`?
p.s When I reach slide no 16 impress.js adds `step-16` in url

Comment: You can listen to `"impress:stepenter"`

Comment: Please consider posting it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("impress:stepenter",function() {
x = document.activeElement;
console.log(x);
if(x.classList[2] == "impress-on-step-16")
      {
         document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = "Graph | Traversals | Breadth First Search"
      }
}
```

)